# Why re.sub(r'\n$', '', "\n\n") gives "" instead of "\n"?

Tags: python, python-re

Is this intended?
Logically re.sub(r'\n$', '', "\n\n") should give "\n". But when I try, it gives me "".
Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks.

Verified in Python 3.10.12

```py
re.sub(r'\n$', '', "\n\n") # ""
```

Expect: "\n"
Actual: ""

In contrast:

```py
re.sub(r'a$', '', "aa") # "a"
```

The result is "a" as expected.

Comment: @tripleee I saw the signature is "re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)"? Also please check out the "In contrast" section I just added.

Comment: @tripleee It's not a bug.  The problem is that `\n\n` is treated as two input lines, so you end up with two end-of-line matches.

Comment: @TomKarzes Will you post that as an answer?

Comment: @tripleee I don't understand it well enough to post a good answer.  Also, some changes were made to `re` after the version of Python that I'm running.  I would prefer it if Python simply treated a string as a string, but it likes to look for newlines.  There's a flag called `re.MULTILINE` that enables some of this, but I'm not sure how to fully turn it off.

Comment: @TomKarzes That seems kinda weird. I tested `re.sub(r"a$", '', "a\na\n")` and the result is 'a\n\n'. Which is even more confusing. So is there any flag to fix this problem? I mean getting "\n" when replacing "\n$" with "" for "\n\n".

Comment: @TomKarzes I tried re.MULTILINE and the results are as follow:
`re.sub(r"a$", '', "a\na\n", flags=re.MULTILINE)` gives '\n\n'
`re.sub(r"\n$", '', "\n\n", flags=re.MULTILINE)` gives "" still.

Comment: @Donny I've run into this before, and I agree that it's stupid.  The bottom line is that `$` doesn't do what you'd like it to do.  I think I found another way to do it though - I just need to remember what I did.

Comment: And then (with `\Z`) it works, I think: https://ideone.com/jDpPOE

Comment: @Donny Ok, I think this is what you want:  Instead of using `$` in your pattern, which matches "end of line", use `\Z`, which matches "end of string".  For example:  `re.sub(r'\n\Z', '', "\n\n")` produces the desired result of `'\n'`.  This is what I've used when I ran into this before.

Comment: @tevemadar It works for me. Thank you. It feels weird that we have to use \Z instead of $ to work around this problem. You save my day.

Comment: @TomKarzes It works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` and `$` basically match the same positions. If you wanted to say `"\n"` adjacent to the end of the input *string*" instead of ... "adjacent to end of line" (which of course trivially every `\n` will match), the notation for that is

```
re.sub(r'\n\Z', '', '\n\n')
```

Comment: So, at the end @TomKarzes and me put together it for you... Don't forget linking the documentation too, https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-36

Comment: Actually I didn't see your comment until now. But fair; I have marked this as community.